# Linear approximation of 3D function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, linear-approximation, linearization

I've looked around and can't find anyone with my exact issue. Also, please forgive me, this is cross posted from Reddit:

I'm trying to do some homework and I can't get my online homework system to accept my answer to a question. I swear I'm getting the right answer, I've worked through it multiple times, had a friend work through it, plugged the derivations into Symbolab, everything is coming out with my same answers but the website keeps saying it's wrong. At this point, either I'm missing something fundamental, or the website is flat out wrong.

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong it would be very very appreciated!

Question as given on homework assignment:

[image]

Example given with this question to show how it should be solved:

[image]

My attempt at a solution:

[image]

Edit: Found out what my problem was. I never actually had to do 2D linear approximations, which probably would have been useful in knowing that I'm supposed to multiply not by x, but by the difference between x and x_0 (or whatever you want to call the given point). I guess I should have inferred that from all the 2D questions I found while reserching this, but I didn't put that together til just now. Oops.

Comment: You will attract more readers and responses if you type out everything. Please learn MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @flowermouth: Are you sure you are using the correct equation? Look at the 2D case (second item): http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21a_fall_06/handouts/linearization.pdf? The example works properly because $(x_0, y_0) = (0, 0)$. In other words, I think you want $L(x, y) = f(x_0,y_0) + f_x(x_0, y_0)(x - x_0) + f_y(x_0, y_0)(y - y_0)$.